# Upgrading to Springboot 3: 'org.springframework.hateoas.server.LinkRelationProvider' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, upgrade, spring-hateoas, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am upgrading my springboot app from 2.7.x to 3.0.0, I have made required changes for jakartaEE. When starting my app I am getting the below error

> {"@timestamp":"2023-01-03T15:28:01.149Z","@version":"1","message":"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION
> FAILED TO
> START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\nParameter
> 1 of method collectionModelContentConverter in
> org.springdoc.core.configuration.SpringDocHateoasConfiguration
> required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.hateoas.server.LinkRelationProvider' that could
> not be found.\r\n\r\n\r\nAction:\r\n\r\nConsider defining a bean of
> type 'org.springframework.hateoas.server.LinkRelationProvider' in your
> configuration.\r\n","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000}

I am using hateos lib for representation in my app, Also I am using `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` for swagger UI.

When I disable configuration for api-docs `springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false` the above error go away but my swagger page is also gone, which definitely means this is not the solution.

Could someone please guide me why this bean is not getting found with springboot 3 while it was all working before with springboot2.7.x and java-11.

here is my pom.xml https://gist.github.com/bruce2019/c93a16dc20f7edb7d922b1e284f39d15

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must use SpringDoc v2. https://springdoc.org/v2/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am using that only as mentioned in the question <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml

Comment: @SimonMartinelli https://gist.github.com/bruce2019/c93a16dc20f7edb7d922b1e284f39d15

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the springdoc.enable-hateoas property to false in your configuration. For more information refer to [springdoc-openapi documentation](https://springdoc.org/v2/#springdoc-openapi-core-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui with 2.0.2 version
Add "/v3/api-docs/**" to mvcMatchers in WebSecurityCustomizer